# Camel JMS : consume a message(is an xml) from topic and invoke a java bean and pass the xml object to it

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I have a camel route which is supposed to consume a JMS message from a topic and invoke a spring bean.
Route definition

```
from("jms:topic:testQueue?transacted=true&connectionFactory=#myJmsConnectionFactory&messageConverter=#myMessageConverter")
.autoStartup("true")
.to("bean:myService?method=consumeJMSMessage")
.routeId("myRouteId.consumeJMSMessages");
```

My question is that where is the xml read and where can i access it, not sure how to pass it to my service method consumeJMSMessage() which currently takes no arguments?

Appreciate any help on this.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in from clause; you are using **myMessageConverter** bean. Camel looks up the specified bean from spring application context. This bean needs to implement the [MessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MessageConverter.html) interface. So if you need to customize conversion of JMS message to XML dom then you need to implement a bean implementing this interface.

Comment: So you are saying that i should add this conversion logic to fromMessage() and return an xml? basically what i want to do is to unmarshal this xml to a java bean in my service layer so the confusion is how to access this message contents in my service layer using camel route syntax?

Comment: Yes, now the XML shall be available in the body of camel exchange. Use the parameter binding [annotations](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html) to get handle of XML. So your method in service shall look like consumeJMSMessage(@Body Document message)

Comment: Thanks, let me try this option.